# AngularJs template and content sharing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am creating simple mobile App using Ionic framework and AngularJs. I have AngularJs view for "single item". I that view I have:

```
<script> js of social sharing plugin </script>
```

My social sharing plugin offers config for url and title of data that will be shared:

```
<script>

Init.share('.share,
{

  url: '',
  title: ''

});
</script>
```

How can I combine AngularJs interpolated data in script config, something like this (any sugestions):

```
  <script>

Init.share('.share,
{

  url: {{data.url}},
  title: {{data.title}}

});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't really see what you're doing there. But normally in your controller you access your variables using $scope. Like $scope.data.url.

Comment: I want to acces my data inside of my html view (template). In my template I have <script></script>. How to access that data inside of inline script.

Comment: I didn't understand why you have to put it in your view with <script> tag instead of putting it in the controller

Comment: I am not sxpirienced :)Thank you for your reply !

Comment: Usually all the script should go in your AngularJS Controller, and there you can access your data using $scope. There are some videos on youtube where you can find nice examples.

Comment: I gave a more complete answer with some examples and links so you could accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your variables in your controller using the `$scope` object. Like `$scope.data.url`

[This](http://youtu.be/i9MHigUZKEM) is a very nice tutorial to start with Angular.

[This](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) is one of the most famous plugin for social sharing using cordova/phonegap apps

Then you can do something like this in your view:

```
<a ng-click="share()">share this</a>
```

And in your controller you can do this

```
$scope.share = function() {
            window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Text to be shared', null, null, 'http://url.here');
        };
```